# pywin32 odbc.pyd DLL load failed

Tags: python, import, odbc, pywin32

I am setting up a website server that I have had running on other Windows 10 machines that uses `ODBC` to connect to a 64 Bit .`accdb database`(64 bit Python, `64 Bit pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.5` , 64 bit Access) but have hit a problem I believe is to do with the machine having been originally set up with 32bit Office. `import odbc.pyd` fails on PC when running scripts from apache web server.  Running script from within Python shell works.  I think it is a dll dependency that is OK from within the Python environment but when externally hosted by Apache is not there. I have tried uninstalling all office components. Installed the MS Access Runtime component only and various visual C++ redistributables.  I have also run `mt.exe -inputresource:C:\python35\ python35.dll;#2 -outputresource:odbc.pyd` without error, but I suspect there are some dlls I need to register.
    import odbc[ImportError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3RGr.jpg)

I have also noticed that both the Microsoft Access Runtime 2016 and Python 3.5 pywin32-220 show "Unavailable" in Windows 10 "Apps and Features"

Update:
I have run `Dependency Walker` on `odbc.pyd`. It returned many "The system cannot find the file specified"  for `API-MS-WIN-CORE` dll's.  I did a file search and found dll's which I copied into the same directory as `odbc.pyd` then re ran dependency walker which found the files but showed them as "not bound"
Also installed `Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10` as many of the dlls referenced are included in this package.

I also ran Dependency Walker on my working development machine and got the same missing dll's so I think Dependency Walker may be a dead end.

Comment: Downloaded and installed "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010" redistributable and fixed this issue

Comment: Note: Must run the pywin install as Administrator, it will install without running as administrator but will not register the dll's corectly